# References for Names of Various Parametric Curves

Tags: reference-request, terminology, curves, parametric

I've been using quite a few 3D parametric curves recently, where the X, Y, and Z components are defined by some function of t. For example:

$t\in\{-\pi,\pi\}$

$x=sin(2t)$

$y=sin(t)$

$z=sin(t)$

To create a simple curve like this:

[image]

I'm guessing a curve like this has a name, but I don't know what references I could use to find it. Are there any references that list names for 3d parametric curves like the one above?

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are called "[Lissajous Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve)". A reference you may consider for looking up different curves: [A Catalog of Special Plane Curves](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486602885) by J. Dennis Lawrence.